# How DevAppsDirect Runs Android library demos without installing them

Tags: android

I came across a Google Play Store app named DevAppsDirect it's very awesome app.
Installing and running this app on my mobile I got a question :: 
**How DevAppsDirect Runs Android library demos without installing them?**

Before running any Demo the app(DevAppsDirect) downloads it and then runs it.
I am wondering what is happening under the hood?

Can anyone please give a hint or explanation how it is done?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is done by [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html). It is a nice feature but u must be aware of the security risk if you are building production grade system. what basically happens they download the compiled dex at runtime and load it.